# Source for pthread for 64 bit windows

Tags: open-source, pthreads, win64

I have an open-source project that must build under Win32/Win64/Linux/MacOSX.

We would like to use pthreads to support our multithreading paradigm, however as my project is open-source everything must be build from source. As such I need the source-code file(s) for a version of pthreads that will compile on Win64.

Does anyone know where I can find said file(s)?

Comment: According to the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797690/portability-of-pthreads-win32-over-various-compilers it apparently builds for x64 and is usable for at least a few users.  You can get source here: http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct replacement for pthreads, but SDL2 features a threading interface that closely resembles pthreads, and will let you build on linux,osx,windows,android,ios.

[SDL2 thread support](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryThread?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryCategory%5Cb%29)

[SDL2 mutex/cond var support](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryMutex?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryCategory%5Cb%29)